# How is redirecting output to `/dev/null` implemented in shells to result in detaching of background processes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

## Context: Backup software executing hook scripts

I have a use-case in which a backup software is able to execute shell scripts as hooks before, after etc. doing some backup. This si done to optionally setup an environment in which it is safe to take backups, e.g. by creating file system level snapshots, mounting those and read the backups from the mount. Therefore that backup software by default waits until the hook script finishes.

I've implemented a slightly different use-case by executing additional background processes within that hook script to read data from within some VMs using SSH and outputs the read content into named pipes. Writing to named pipes block until a reader is attached and vice-versa, so the started background processes really need to execute concurrently with the backup software being the reader of the pipes. For this to happen, the main hook script needed to finish, so that the waiting backup software could continue.

## Problem: Wrong redirection results in hook-zombie

[This didn't work as expected](https://superuser.com/questions/1717487/how-to-properly-make-a-ssh-call-locally-async-background-independent): The backup software waited forever for the hook script to finish, because I had some redirection wrong. While I executed commands in the background and those commands for themself worked as expected, the redirection of the commands output was done by the hook script itself. That made that hook script at some point left around as a zombie never finishing at all, so the backup software couldn't continue.

```bsh
(
  trap '' HUP INT
  ${cmd_exec} <<< "${cmd}"
) < '/dev/null' > "${PATH_LOCAL_MNT2}/${db_name}" 2> '/dev/null' &
```

vs.

```bsh
(
  trap '' HUP INT
  ${cmd_exec} <<< "${cmd}" > "${PATH_LOCAL_MNT2}/${db_name}"
) < '/dev/null' > '/dev/null' 2> '/dev/null' &
```

I think I understand what happens now: Someone simply needs to actually read and write data as part of some redirection. At least if shell level redirection is used compared to e.g. commands writing to files on their own. I'm using SSH which doesn't seem to be able to do so and seems to entirely rely on shell level redirection.

With the second code above I'm creating a subshell being executed in the background, that subshell is redirecting the output of SSH into some file and the parent shell detaches from all the input and output of the created subshell. That detaching is actually what makes the hook script NOT becoming a zombie, it simply doesn't need to handle any redirection anymore.

## Question

Here's what I don't understand currently: Redirecting to a file resulted in a zombie shell instance taking care of reading SSH output and writing it to the file. From my understanding, there's really some process actively reading the SSH output and writing it to the file, isn't it? If so, why doesn't the same process need to actively read data and write it to `/dev/null`? That would result in a zombie staying around as well, but that's not the case obviously. Instead, redirecting to `/dev/null` is documented everywhere to detach from the associated channel like STDIN, STDOUT etc.

Why is that? Why and how is redirecting to `/dev/null` handled specially or am I understanding the whole redirection process still wrong and there's not really the shell instance actively reading and writing data on it's own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're reinventing the `nohup` tool here...

---

> Someone simply needs to actually read and write data as part of some redirection. At least if shell level redirection is used compared to e.g. commands writing to files on their own.

Generally no, shell level redirection (that is, specifically `<`, `>` and `>>`) is indistinguishable from the program opening the file on its own: it always directly inherits a file descriptor from the shell that points to the already open file.

However, it *may* be true for `<<` and `<<<` because they specify inline strings so there *isn't* a file that could be opened, so instead a shell subprocess has to actively provide the data. This depends on the shell version.

> From my understanding, there's really some process actively reading the SSH output and writing it to the file, isn't it?

As above – usually no, there isn't. All file-based redirections directly replace the child process' stdin or stdout file descriptor with one associated with the specified file.

The shell forks; the child process closes and opens its file descriptors according to redirections; and the child process exec's (replaces itself with) the command to be run. If an interactive `do_backup` command would have its stdin & stdout attached to the tty of the terminal it's running in, then a `do_backup > log.txt` has its stdout directly attached to the `log` file in write mode; `do_backup > /dev/null` is handled in the same way.

But one possible exception is when there *is* no file, specifically using `<<` and `<<<` redirections where you specify a literal string. The shell has few choices here: either it creates a temporary file in /tmp (with the specified contents) and attaches *that* to the process' stdin, or it uses a pipe between a sub-shell process and the command (i.e. transforming `foo <<< bar` to `echo bar | foo`).

Older Bash versions used to create a temporary file when `<<<` was used, but newer ones (e.g. 5.1.16) instead use a pipe – in which case a subshell process has to linger around until it has finished writing everything into the pipe (as pipes have a limited capacity buffer).

---

Note that besides file descriptors, processes also have the concept of "controlling tty" that they remain attached to even if their stdin/stdout/stderr no longer points to the tty device. The `setsid` tool can be used to detach processes from their controlling terminal.

(You could also start the processes not attached in the first place, using the systemd service manager's `systemd-run` tool.)

Two more tricks related to SIGHUP are to either use `disown` after starting the background task, or to use `&` *inside* the subshell, i.e. `(cmd &)`. It is often the shell itself that delivers SIGHUPs to background jobs; 'disown' tells it to stop tracking a specific job, while starting it from a subshell prevents it from being tracked in the first place. Neither prevents SIGHUP from other sources, however.

Comment: The different implementation of `nohup` is only a side-effect, that wasn't the problem at all. The problem was with redirection, like in the following example as well: `nohup ssh -F ${PATH_LOCAL_SSH_CFG} -f -n ${HOST_OTHER} ${cmd} < '/dev/null' > "${PATH_LOCAL_MNT2}/${db_name}" 2> '/dev/null' &` That didn't work and left a shell zombie, while changing file redirection to `/dev/null` didn't, but didn't fit my use-case obviously. So why the zombie for file redirection vs. not when the shell isn't reading/waiting for anything anymore?